# Is it possible to pass PostCSS cssnext customProperties variables from `css` file

Tags: webpack, postcss, css-variables, cssnext

When using PostCSS with webpack, I'm using `postcss-cssnext` with this options for custom properties:

```
pcssNext({
        features: {
            customProperties: {
                variables: {
                    'button-border-radius': '10px'
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Im using the `variables` option to override variables defined in some node module (`react-toolbox` for instance).

Is it possible to pass a `css` file path to `variables` some how? for example:

```
pcssNext({
        features: {
            customProperties: {
                variables: './myOverrideVars.css'
            }
        }
    })
```

And in my `myOverrideVars.css` file:

```
:root {
    --button-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

It's kind of annoying that I must use JavaScript to override css params..

Answer (score 0):

Make an object file that contains your css variables and then import it inside the cssnext `customProperties.variables`